# C++ Bitwise XOR ^ Not Working

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, xor

The C++ Xor is ^. So if I:

```
a ^ b
```

it should do a XOR b

However when the values are 4246661 0 so

```
4246661 ^ 0
```

it prints: 4246661 when it really should be 0.

EDIT: Wow I was going off  of an online xor calculator which was giving me weird results.. sorry

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think it should be 0? You might want to refresh yourself on exactly what XOR does.

Comment: It really should be 4246661. Now if it was `&` (bitwise AND) it should be 0...

Comment: If you want it to be `0` you must `XOR` it with itself - this is a well-known "cheap" way of zeroing a CPU register.

Comment: Yeah, a fundamental mathematical operation of a language millions of people have been using for decades is broken. It couldn't possibly be that you misunderstand it. :-)

Comment: C++ Bitwise XOR not working? In what language does XOR works like you expect?

Answer (score 6):

XOR result is 1 if one and only one of the two values is 1, meaning:

- 0 XOR 0 is 0
- 0 XOR 1 is 1
- 1 XOR 0 is 1
- 1 XOR 1 is 0

So, (`4246661 XOR 0`), which is (`0b10000001100110010000101 XOR 0b0`) result is `0b10000001100110010000101`...no problem here!

`Anything` XOR 0 result is `Anything`

Answer (score 1):

Doing an exclusive or of any number with 0 yields that same number.

bitwise:

1  OR  0  = 1

1 EOR  0 = 1

1 EOR 1 = 0

with numbers :

nbr OR 0 = nbr

nbr EOR 0 = nbr